# How to create an 'Add item' contextual link for views?

Tags: 7, views, navigation

I like the concept of [contextual links in D7](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/contextual) and want to push it a bit further: I want views to have an 'Add item' contextual link, so the site administrator can easily add new items.

Of course I could add an 'Add item' button to the view's footer instead. But I need to show it only to users who have the appropriate permission to add items.

Is there an idiomatic way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the [Custom Contextual Links](http://drupal.org/project/ccl) module. I haven't personally used it but it looks like it does what you're after. It also supports views as of 7.x-1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to the 'views header'.

It provides links to adding new items to the node collection or reordering.

## 1 Edit view

## 2 'Add' Global: Text area

## 3 set text format to 'PHP code'.

## 4 add the following code.

```
<?php
/* header for list */
global $user;
if (user_access('create document content', $user)) {
  $path = '/news/list';
  $addLink = l(t('Add news'), 'node/add/article', array('query' =>               
  array('destination' => $path)));
  print $addLink;
  $viewLink = l(t('View news'), '/news');
  print $viewLink;
  $listLink = l(t('Edit/reorder news'), '/news/list');
  print $listLink;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, this will provide the functionality, just not in the views "[contextual links](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/contextual)" section on the frontend. That's the name for the on-hover "gear and triangle" styled dropdown shown to administrative users in the top right corner of views etc..